# Let's look like the function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let's look like the function $ f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  $f(x+iy)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ fulfills the Cauchy Riemann conditions in (0,0) but is not derivable in origin

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt{\cdot}$? Remember, that function has a branch cut from the origin to $\infty$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Since the argument is non-negative, though, there should be no reasonable ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations, it is remarked that for $f$ to be holomorphic the CR equations are not sufficient, $f$ should also be real differentiable. But that is not the case here: the function $t \mapsto f(t,t)$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

For this functions, $u(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ and $v(x,y)=0$. So, $v_x(0,0)=v_y(0,0)=0$. On the other hand$$(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}):u(x,0)=u(0,y)=0$$and therefore $u_x(0,0)=u_y(0,0)=0$. So, yes, $u_x(0,0)=v_y(0,0)$ and $u_y(0,0)=-v_x(0,0)$. Now, prove that $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks Jose Carlos Santos >)